# MRTK v2 Spatial Mapping Hide the Visualization of Polygons

Tags: mapping, spatial, hololens, mrtk

**How to hide the visualization of polygons？**

I used the following method, but it still failed.

```
// Get the first Mesh Observer available, generally we have only one registered
var observer = CoreServices.GetSpatialAwarenessSystemDataProvider<IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessMeshObserver>();

// Set to not visible
observer.DisplayOption = SpatialAwarenessMeshDisplayOptions.None;
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked into an old project, where I enabled and disabled spatial mapping. I guess you have to resume the observer, after changing the `DisplayOption`. Thats how I did that:

```
public void ToggleObservers()
{
    if (SpatialAwarenessSystem == null) return;

    // If running → stop "running"
    if (_isObserverRunning)
    {
        SetVisualizationOfSpatialMapping(SpatialAwarenessMeshDisplayOptions.None);
        SpatialAwarenessSystem.SuspendObservers();
        _isObserverRunning = false;

        // Disabling the whole system boosts performance ~+5fps
        if (ShouldSpatialSystemBeDisabled)
        {
            SpatialAwarenessSystem.Disable();
            Debug.Log("Spatial map system was disabled.");
        }            
    } // Else start spatial mapping
    else
    {
        SpatialAwarenessSystem.Enable();
        SetVisualizationOfSpatialMapping(SpatialAwarenessMeshDisplayOptions.Visible);
        SpatialAwarenessSystem.ResumeObservers();
        _isObserverRunning = true;
    }
}

public void SetVisualizationOfSpatialMapping(SpatialAwarenessMeshDisplayOptions option)
{
    if (CoreServices.SpatialAwarenessSystem is IMixedRealityDataProviderAccess provider)
    {
        foreach (var observer in provider.GetDataProviders())
        {
            if (observer is IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessMeshObserver meshObs)
            {
                meshObs.DisplayOption = option;
            }
        }
    }
}

private IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessSystem SpatialAwarenessSystem
{
    get
    {
        if (_spatialAwarenessSystem == null)
        {
            MixedRealityServiceRegistry.TryGetService<IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessSystem>(out _spatialAwarenessSystem);
        }
        return _spatialAwarenessSystem;
    }
}
```